# Read directory name and size into associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I want to get the name and size of all directories [at the top level] of a specified directory into an associative array, such that the name is used as the key and the size as the value.

I know that I can use `mapfile` to read the output of a command (this extracts the directory size) into an indexed array:

`mapfile -t inter_arry < <( du -d0 "$completePath"* | sed -E 's/^([0-9]*).*$/\1/' );`

(I would then loop through this array and use it to populate the associative array.)

1. I know that I *could* create a matching array and populate it with the directory name (though there's no way of knowing if there's been a change in the contents between commands), but how can I extract both the size and the name by modifying my code snippet?
2. Is there any way to skip the intermediate indexed array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many items, it's faster, though not prettier, to avoid a loop. Here I use `du | awk` to create the array initialization string:

```
declare -A ARR=$(
  echo '( '$(
    du -d0 "$completePath"* |
      awk -F$'\t' '{printf "["$2"]="$1" "}'
  )')'
)
```

If there are few items (e.g., thousands or less), use a loop as @Inian suggests:

```
declare -A ARR

while IFS=$'\t' read size name; do
    ARR[$name]=$size
done < <(du -d0 "$completePath"*)
```

Comment: Thank you. There are relatively few items to process, so the loop solution gives me what I need and without the need for an intermediate indexed array.